# Noob question about $\int \frac{1}{x}$ dx

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

I took 3 online solvers and ask them to calculate $\int \frac{1}{x} dx$.
And got the following:

1) $ln|x| + C$ from https://www.symbolab.com/solver/definite-integral-calculator/

2) $log(x) + C$ from http://www.wolframalpha.com

3) $ln(|x|) + C$ from http://www.integral-calculator.com/

I have complete mess in my brain now. Should I put module to $x$ or not?
Why wolfram alpha give its answer without module?

I am confused because I often meet this in textbooks and online solvers, some of them put module some of them not - without any comments

Comment: What's your domain?

Comment: Integral solving + differential equations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, use $\log|x|$ as this is valid for negative $x$'s as well.

Wolfram Alpha uses a more "advanced" convention that relies on complex numbers. As you will later learn, in the complex one can define

$$\log(-x)=\log x+i\pi.$$

As the extra term is a constant, if vanishes when you differentiate so that

$$\int\frac{dx}x=\log x+C$$ is correct.

---

A difference appears when you consider definite integrals.

In particular

$$\int_{-a}^b\frac{dx}x=\left.\log|x|\right|_{-a}^b=\log\frac ba$$ is wrong because you cannot cross the singularity at $x=0$ (this is an improper integral).

Using the other convention, you get

$$\int_{-a}^b\frac{dx}x=\left.\log x\right|_{-a}^b=\log\left(-\frac ba\right),$$

warning you that "there is something wrong".

Comment: So the right answer is do not use modules if we are in complex space and do not try definitive integrals from $1/x$ in we are in real space?

Comment: @MaratZakirov: more precisely, do not integrate across the singularity.

Comment: but singularity still exists in complex space, isn't it?

Comment: @MaratZakirov: absolutely.

Comment: Key phrase here
warning you that "there is something wrong".  
Ok thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In $(0, \infty): \int \frac{1}{x} dx= \ln(x)+C$,

in $(- \infty, 0): \int \frac{1}{x} dx= \ln(-x)+C$.

Consequence: in $ \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}: \int \frac{1}{x} dx= \ln(|x|)+C$

Comment: So if we consider complex space the correct answer is always without module right?